# Unable to set datagridview column to bold after data loaded in datagridview

Tags: winforms, datagridview, fonts

I am able to make particular column data bold but Unable to set datagridview column data to bold after data loaded in datagridview.

I am using below code to make it Bold which is working if I Set this in columnAdd event but unable to change after data loaded in to the datagridview.

```
 
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Roboto", 8.5F, FontStyle.Bold);
```

please help if its possible.. I am using windows form DataGridView

**2017Button || 2010Button || 2005Button**

**On clicking particular button I need to highlight that particular column. For Example, My data contains 3 Columns 2017 Data, 2010 Data, 2005 Data, Which Year I Select from above button out of 2017,2010,2005 button, that column should get bold.. And also I don't want to rebind the data to gridview**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't change datagridview cell color when using a datasource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515960/cant-change-datagridview-cell-color-when-using-a-datasource)

Comment: No this is not like that, I already mentioned that before data loaded intop gridview I am able to do that. But After Datagridview get loaded I am unable to change..

Comment: On clicking particular button I need to highlight that particular column. For Example, My data contains 3 Columns 2017 Data, 2010 Data, 2005 Data, Which Year I Select from above button out of 2017,2010,2005 button, that column should get bold.. And also I don't want to rebind the data to gridview. This is the actual scenario.

Comment: @VijayKumbhoje.. See above comment.. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You must try it on below event

```
void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Roboto", 8.5F, FontStyle.Bold);
}
```